# Append a recordset to another recordset

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

When doing a LookupRows, if a certain number or records is not returned (6) then we need to retrieve additional records from a default source.

Is there a way to just append to the original recordset?

Something like:

```
SET @rows = LOOKUPROWS("de"...)

IF ROWCOUNT(@rows) < 6 THEN
    SET @rows = @rows + LOOKUPROWS("default"...)
ENDIF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSJS allows you to push one rowset (array) to another, but not AMPScript, so it may be worth considering SSJS instead of AMP for a low volume send. A hacky workaround in AMPScript is to gradually build an XML document in a variable using concatenation as you loop around your various rowsets and then use BuildRowSetFromXML to turn your string that contains your XML document back into your final rowset.

Comment: Would it be something like:   var firstRows = Platform.Function.LookupOrderedRows('CustomerData',2,'LastName ASC','Company','exampleCompany');  var secondRows = Platform.Function.LookupOrderedRows('MoreCustomerData',2,'LastName ASC','Company','exampleCompany'); var allRows = firstRows.concat(secondRows);

Comment: Yes. concat or push would work here I think.